# SVG drop shadow with filters is truncated

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I am trying to make a drop shadow for the following SVG shape:

```
<svg style="overflow:visible; ">
<defs>
    <marker orient="auto" refY="4" refX="2" markerHeight="13" markerWidth="13" id="_x0000_s1094end">
        <path style="fill:yellow; " d="M2,2 L2,6 L6,4 L2,2" />
    </marker>
</defs>
<path d="M 288,164 L 108,176" style="stroke-width:8; stroke:yellow; marker-end:url(#_x0000_s1094end); " y="4" x="4"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

After the drop shadow the shape is suppossed to look like this (ignore the bits except for the arrow and its shadow):

[image]

I tried the following SVG:

```
<svg style="overflow:visible; ">
<defs>
    <marker orient="auto" refY="4" refX="2" markerHeight="13" markerWidth="13" id="_x0000_s1094end">
        <path style="fill:yellow; " d="M2,2 L2,6 L6,4 L2,2" />
    </marker>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="500%" height="500%">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-8" dy="-8" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
</defs>
<path d="M 288,164 L 108,176" style="stroke-width:8; stroke:yellow; marker-end:url(#_x0000_s1094end); " y="4" x="4" filter="url(#f1)"/>
</svg>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/md3rT/

What I get is this:

[image]

The resulting SVG is coming out truncated.
Also, how can I change the opacity of the shadow?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop truncating, just make the filter cover the shape (the drop shadow is above and to the left so the filter needs to cover that region).

```
    <filter id="f1" x="-180%" y="-500%" width="500%" height="1000%">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-8" dy="-8" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
```

If you want the shadow not to be opaque, something involving a non-opaque flood would seem to do the trick. For a general drop shadow you need something like this...

```
<feGaussianBlur in="alpha-channel-of-feDropShadow-in" stdDeviation="stdDeviation-of-feDropShadow"/> 
  <feOffset dx="dx-of-feDropShadow" dy="dy-of-feDropShadow" result="offsetblur"/> 
  <feFlood flood-color="flood-color-of-feDropShadow" flood-opacity="flood-opacity-of-feDropShadow"/> 
  <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/> 
  <feMerge> 
    <feMergeNode/>
    <feMergeNode in="in-of-feDropShadow"/> 
  </feMerge>
```

Although, in Firefox and Chrome you can use the [SVG Filter Effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) `<feDropShadow>` filter or a CSS drop-shadow filter instead.

Comment: Thanx the truncating problem was solved by your suggestion. However using the flood filter didn't work. The flood filter filled the whole filter region (i.e. x="-180%" y="-500%" width="500%" height="1000%") with the specified color.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/2DpBz/ for an actual example of a dropshadow effect using the latter template.

Comment: Surender - this works - check to make sure that you've replaced ALL of Robert's placeholders with your actual values (aka "alpha-channel-of-feDropShadow-in" needs to be replaced with "SourceAlpha".

Answer (score 2):

This is what I think you're looking for. It expands the filter region, keeps the drop shadow unblurred and dials the opacity on the shadow down to 50%. (I've also found browsers to get crotchety when you don't provide explicit dimensions for inline SVG.)

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="300px" style="overflow:visible;" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
    <defs>
        <marker orient="auto" refY="4" refX="2" markerHeight="13" markerWidth="13" id="_x0000_s1094end">
            <path style="fill:yellow; " d="M2,2 L2,6 L6,4 L2,2" />
        </marker>
        <filter id="f1" x="-50%" y="-100%" width="200%" height="400%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-8" dy="-8" />
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 .5"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <path d="M 288,164 L 108,176" style="stroke-width:8; stroke:yellow; marker-end:url(#_x0000_s1094end); " y="4" x="4" filter="url(#f1)"/>

</svg>
```